# How can i include previous row in a selected range if condition is not satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out a maximum number from a given date ranges.

for example, my table contains

```
   date         number
----------     --------
01-01-2019         1
05-01-2019         3
07-01-2019         2
10-01-2019         1
11-01-2019         2
```

and I want to find the max number in date from **06-01-2019** to **11-01-2019**

When I use the query,

```
select max(count) from TABLE where date between startDate and endDate;
```

the output is 2.

But what I wanted is if the startDate is not in the table, to include the previous row. For example in the previous case, I want to include the row **05-01-2019** and thus the output should be 3.

Is there any query for this process or do I need to write an algorithm?

Assume the dates in table are sorted and I use a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `subquery`

```
SELECT MAX(number)
FROM TABLE
WHERE date >= (
    SELECT date
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE date <= startDate
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
AND date <= endDate
```

Subquery will return largest nearest date to startDate.

This date can then be used as a minimum value for your outer query.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `lead()`:

```
select max(number)
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date > $start_date and
      date <= $end_date;
```